# Does google play services for Unity use the profiler?

Tags: debugging, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, logcat

I am trying to debug my game in logcat but when I add the `script debugger` in the build settings my logcat gets flooded with `profiler is only supported in Unity Pro.`. Since I'm not using the profiler and only use the Google Play Services as a 3th party script I suspect it of starting the profiler.

If so, how do I turn that off so I can debug properly? If not, what else could it be?

I have been trying to filter the text message `profiler is only supported in Unity Pro.` out of logcat but without success. I'm using the UI `monitor.bat` in the tools map that come with the Android-SDK. This should be a workaround.

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html - the profiler is a Pro only feature.

The profiler is different from the debug log messages.

To get debug messages out of my app, I call Debug.Log("....") in my scripts, and just run adb logcat and the messages show up:

```
I/Unity   (12241): Status Update: Starting sign-in...
```